# Jenkins access the pom file in github project

Tags: github, jenkins

I want to test Jenkins build on this github project:
https://github.com/kevinsawicki/github-maven-example.git

The issue is that Jenkins can't find the pom.xml since the pom file is located under the example/ directory in the project. However, the root directory cloned from github is workspace/.

In this case, how should I specify github URL to let Jenkins know that the real root of the project is example/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven build step, just specify path to your pom in Root POM:

[image]

If you are using shell build step, follow instructions from the github-maven-example project's readme:

```
$ cd example
$ mvn clean install
```